# Weird OutOfMemory on SharedPreferences Crash

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my application, I save catalogs of products in SharedPreferences in the form of TXT. These txt files have more or less 4mb each.

However when I try to check if the user has already downloaded the catalog (check the directory in SharedPreferences) the application crash

Log:

```
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620): FATAL EXCEPTION: SharedPreferencesImpl-load
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620): Process: br.com.asiatex, PID: 32620
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1345)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:781)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:559)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:809)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:751)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:490)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:120)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:52)
02-05 15:29:34.631: E/AndroidRuntime(32620):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:91)
```

How I'm storing my string

```
private void storeJson(){
        String mPref;
        String mPrefString;
        if (flag == DOWNLOAD_CURTAINS){
            mPref = "mPrefCurtains";
            mPrefString = "jsonCurtains";
        } else if (flag == DOWNLOAD_CARPETS) {
            mPref = "mPrefCarpets";
            mPrefString = "jsonCarpets";
        } else {
            mPref = "mPrefQuits";
            mPrefString = "jsonQuits";
        }
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(mPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();

        prefEditor.putString(mPrefString, result).commit();
    }
```

How I'm checking:

```
public void checkCurtains() {
    Boolean check = false;

    mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mPrefCurtains", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    check = mPrefs.contains("jsonCurtains"); //crashing here on debbug

    if (check) {
        setUpCurtains(true);
    } else {
        setUpCurtains(false);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Just stylish : `if (check) { setUpCurtains(true); } else { setUpCurtains(false); }` --> `setUpCurtains(check);`

Comment: welcome - glad you solved it - try avoiding horizontal scrollbars when posting code - looks and reads better :) - in eclipse activate "wrap lines" formatting - logcats can't be made much better - removing time stamps helps though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, but I managed to make it work with the SharedPreferences.

I removed the variable to the start of class and modified methods, were as follows:

```
public void checkCurtains() {
        Boolean check = false;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mPrefCurtains", MODE_PRIVATE);
        check = mPrefs.contains("jsonCurtains");

        setUpCurtains(check);
    }

private void checkCarpets(){

        Boolean check = false;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mPrefCarpets", MODE_PRIVATE);
        check = mPrefs.contains("jsonCarpets");

        setUpCarpets(check);
    }

private void checkQuits(){
        Boolean check = false;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("mPrefQuits", MODE_PRIVATE);
        check = mPrefs.contains("jsonQuits");

        setUpQuits(check);
    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Actually I had the same error, but I'm only storing a few small values. This answer fixed it... I stopped caching the `StoredPreferences` object on a member variable and called `getSharedPreferences()` every time instead.

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences is not a good choice for storing data.  It is designed to store small, key value pairs such as settings options, user names etc.  You should definitely be using SQLite for this.  I doubt that SharedPrefences has even been tested like this.  Since the strings are held on the heap, you will quickly run out of memory using this approach.  On most devices, you will be able to load, at most, 2 or 3 strings of this size.

I doubt that there is a solution other than SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to long value for any key/node. u should try to save a file in internal storage (private mode)instead of shared prefrences. Writing on file will not have any such issues.